# Design a send a message to group functionality

Tags: sql, database, database-design

I'm developing a social network where users can send messages between them.

At the first time I only support message between users: a user can send a message to another one.

On my database I have this table to store the messages:

[image: Messages table]

`sentBy` and `sentTo` are the `userId` of the users that sent and receive the message.
`type` can be: friendship request or message send to an user.

Now I have to support **GROUPS** and any user can send a message to a group. If a user send a message to a group, the members of the group will receive that message.

I've thought to add a new type to table `Messages` called: send to group. But I need to add the group id to `Message` table to know which is the group. I can use `sentTo` or `sentBy` columns, but these columns represents users.

**How would you do to add this functionality?** 
**Do I need to add another table?**

Comment: Table Inheritance. Party Model. Look em up.

Answer (score 0):

I would consider introducing a new table that stores the mapping of 1 Group to n number of users that belong to that group.

### Groups

```
groupId int PK
userId int FK
```

It's very simple and allows for the following workflow:

1. You can easily add/edit/delete members from a given group.
2. When you want to send a message to a group, you can iterate over the users in that group and create one record in Messages per user in a group.

The obvious downside is that the Messages table can grow very large.

The upside though is that you have detailed reporting/information on every message sent.

If you wanted to know historically what groups had been mailed to, you can either introduce a groupId field to Messages (which feels wrong to me since it will have a decent amount of NULLs) - or you can make a separate log table that logs who was emailed in a group.

Comment: If the group-to-user relationship is one-to-many, and you don't need to store any attributes of the group except its members, then this could work. If you want to store the name of the group or any other attributes, you could add a new column, but you'll duplicate the data as many times as there are users in the group.

Comment: If you decouple messages from users and groups and relate them to addresses instead, you avoid the problem of logging mail to groups and users in different ways. All mail comes from and goes to addresses, and all users and groups have an address.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need five tables:

- Users
- Groups
- Membership
- Addresses
- Messages

Users and Messages already have their own tables. So far, so good.

You asked about how to model groups, and how to model messages between groups or users.

## Groups

Groups should have their own table so you can store attributes of the group. The table should have at least a groupId column.

How do users relate to groups? Can a user be in multiple groups? No groups? Exactly one group?

If a user can be in at most one group, you could add an extra groupId column to the Users table to store group membership.

If the user can be in multiple groups, you'll need an extra Membership table with a userId column and a groupId column.

If the user can be in 0 or 1 groups, then you could make the groupId column nullable, or use use a dummy 'not-in-a-group' row in the Groups table. The dummy row would make some analytical queries easier to write.

If the user can be in 0 to many groups, then you could model 'not-in-a-group simply by an absence of rows in the Membership table for that user.

## Messages

Messages are sent from one *address* to another. You can model this with an Addresses table.

The Addresses table should have at least an addressId column.

Change the sentBy and sentTo columns of the Messages table to refer to the Addresses table.

It sounds like each user or group should have exactly one address. Add an addressId column to the Users and Groups tables. The column should reference the addressId column of the Addresses table.